# Linear Dependence Lemma Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ is a linearly dependent list in $V$. Then there exists $j \in \{1, 2 \ldots, m\}$ such that the following hold:
>
> (a) $v_j \in \mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_{j-1})$;
>
> (b) if the $j$th term is removed from $v_1, \ldots, v_m$, the span of the remaining list equals $\mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$.

At the end of Axler's proof of (a), he writes vector $v_j$ in terms of vectors $v_1$ to $v_{j-1}$ as $v_j \in \mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_{j-1})$;  (I didn't include the entire proof of (a) as I didn't feel like it was relevant)

Shortened Axler's proof of (b): Suppose $u \in \mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$. There then exist numbers $c_1. . . c_m$ $\in$ **F** such that $u=c_1v_1+ ... +c_mv_m$. He then substitutes vector $v_j$ with the result that was found in (a) thus proving that $u$ is in the span of the list without vector $v_j$, thus proving (b)

My question/confusion: How does showing that $u$ is in both spans show that the spans are equal to one another?

My thinking (Please correct me if I'm wrong): I believe Axler's proof of (b) shows that span($v_1,...,v_m$) is a subset of the span$(v_1,...v_{j-1},v_{j+1},v_m)$. And that it is obvious that the span$(v_1,...v_{j1},v_{j+1},v_m)$ is a subset of span of the list $(v_1,...,v_m)$. Therefore, the two spans are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that $\textrm{span}(V) \subseteq \textrm{span}(V \cup v)$ was already proven earlier in the text, so proving that $\textrm{span}(V \cup v) \subseteq \textrm{span}(V)$ is already enough to show that the spans must be equal.

Comment: May I ask what v denotes in the union between V U v, does it denote the removed vector? I don't believe it was proved earlier. Also, is my thinking correct of showing that they are subsets of one another thus they must be equal?

Comment: Yes, I should have written $V \cup \{v\}$, but I was essentially going from the other direction by having $V$ be the reduced set of vectors and $\{v\}$ the one that was removed. I would be surprised if there weren't *some* kind of proof stating that a "bigger" set will have bigger span than a smaller one, since it's not something you should just assume to be true. It might have been formulated as $\textrm{span}(U) \subseteq \textrm{span}(U \cup V)$, or maybe that $U \subseteq V \implies \textrm{span}(U) \subseteq \textrm{span}(V)$.

Comment: Thank you, I just flipped through the chapter and still cannot find anything about it. I feel like Axler may have just left that part out as he thought it was redundant to state in the text.